# ACF repeater inside group

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, repeater

I tried to get ACF repeater from the group field.
I must be blind, but I cannot find a mistake inside my code.

```
<?php if( have_rows( 'acf_group' ) ): ?>
    
    <?php while( have_rows( 'acf_group' ) ): the_row(); ?>

        <?php if( have_rows( 'acf_repeater' ) ): ?>
    
        <ul>
    
            <?php while( have_rows( 'acf_repeater' ) ): the_row();
                
                $link_text = get_sub_field( 'acf_repeater_field_text' );
                $link_url = get_sub_field( 'acf_repeater_field_url' );
            ?>
    
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $link_url; ?>"><?php echo $link_text; ?></a>
            </li>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
            
        </ul>

        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I think that there is no issue in your code. so please check the acf structure. Did you test that acf_group data is got?

Comment: @WebKing Yes, I also tried this code which works.
But I want to find my mistake in the code above.
`code`<?php

if ( have_rows( 'acf_group' ) ) {
 while ( have_rows( 'acf_group' ) ) {
  the_row();
  if ( have_rows( 'acf_repeater' ) ) {
   echo '<ul>';
   while ( have_rows( 'acf_repeater' ) ) {
    the_row();
    $link_text = get_sub_field( 'acf_repeater_field_text' );
    $link_url = get_sub_field( 'acf_repeater_field_url' );

    printf( '<li>%s: %s</li>', $link_text, $link_url );
   }
   echo '</ul>';
  }
 }
}

?>`code`